# Как воспользоваться telnet на андроиде через ethernet кабель?

Tags: android, linux, сеть, ssh, telnet

Не могу понять, как заставить работать telnet на андроиде. Нужно достучаться до другого устройства подключенного к телефону через переходник type-c > ethernet и соответственно витую пару. Скачивал ssh и telnet клиенты и они просто не делают этого. При вводе telnet 192.168.x.x, как это происходит на винде, клиенты на андроид просто выдают сообщение, что это не возможно или около того, при том устройство с клиента пингуется. Видел сообщения на форуме, что нужно как-то настроить telnet через adb и якобы рутировать телефон, но толком так и не понял. Так же не могу попасть на веб-интерфейс устройства, хотя настроил статичный айпи на телефоне. Думаю, что это возможно из-за отсутствия маски подсети, но не уверен. Помогите, пожайлуйста, разобраться возможно ли то, что я хочу и как это сделать?